# MySQL | The user specified as a definer ('test'@'%') does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, database, mariadb

In my `phpmyadmin` i have a database called "testDB" and with my command line i'm trying to export the database, but every time i try to run this command i get `mysql` error 1449:

```
mysqldump -u root -p testDB > data-dump.sql
```

the error is this:
"The user specified as a definer ('myuser'@'%') does not exist" when using LOCK TABLES"

I analyzed the sql file and saw that this username appears only once at the bottom of the file:

```
"/* 50013 DEFINER='myuser'@'%' sql security definer */"
```

Without export database and without create an new user because i can't, how can i do for resolve this issue?

Is it possible to replace this value with a specific SQL command for my database?

**Details of my server:**

-`Apache/2.4.29`

-`MariaDB 10.4.18`

-`PHP 7.4.18`

Answer (score 1):

The username appears only once at the bottom because `mysqldump` exited before finishing the data export. There are two possible solutions that I can think of off the top of my head:

1. If you have a table, routine, and trigger creation file available, you can export *just* the data:

   ```
   mysqldump -u [user] -p --no-create-info testDB > data-dump.sql
   ```
2. If “nobody is watching”, then you can create a `'myuser'@'%'` account temporarily, grant the appropriate privileges, perform the dump, then remove the user. You are performing the data export with `root`, so you have the keys to the castle:

   ```
   mysql > CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
   mysql > GRANT USAGE ON `testDB`.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
   mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   mysql > exit;
   ```

   Then dump the data:

   ```
   $ mysqldump -u root -p testDB > data-dump.sql
   ```

   Then remove the user account (if necessary):

   ```
   mysql > DROP USER 'myuser'@'%';
   mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   mysql > exit;
   ```

   If you wish to remove the `DEFINER` line from the SQL export, you can do that after `mysqldump` completes with `sed`:

   ```
   sed -i 's/DEFINER=[^*]*\*/\*/g' data-dump.sql
   ```
3. If you want to do this “the DBA way”, modify the `DEFINER` for all objects in the database. [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4131/228577) on the DBA Stack site can get you started with how to accomplish this goal. Once done, you shouldn’t see the error again.

Comment: How to pipe sed between gunzip and mysql?